# Will initWithFrame: trigger init?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, subclass, init

I made a subclass of UIImageView and I want to add something to be triggered whenever I call initWithFrame or initWithImage or Init...

```
-(id) init {
  [super init];
  NSLog(@"Init triggered.");
}
```

If I call `-initWithFrame:` method, will the `-init` above be triggered as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every class is supposed to have a [designated initialiser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW3). If `UIImageView` follows this convention (it should, but I haven't tested it) then you'll find that calling `-init` will end up calling `-initWithFrame:`.

If you want to ensure that your init method is run, all you have to do is override the designated initialiser of the parent class, either like this:

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){
        //do initialisation here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Or like this:

```
//always override superclass's designated initialiser
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    return [self initWithSomethingElse];
}

-(id) initWithSomethingElse;
{
    //always call superclass's designated initializer
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero])){
        //do initialisation here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: +1 but please start your init methods withn `init` to keep with the naming conventions.

Comment: Whoops, I'm too quick to pull out "foo" or "bar" or "myFunction" when I'm making up names for demonstration.